# How to make regular expression that counts a specific word as the whole words?

Tags: php, regex

How to make regular expression that counts a specific word as the whole words and **NOT** the part of the word?
For example:

```
$str = "Brains Brainsgdfgdfgdfgfdg"; // 1 count of word
echo substr_count($str, "Brains");
```

Output:

```
2
```

I've tried to do that way:

```
$str = "Brains Brains Brainsasdasdas Brains"; // 3 count of word
echo substr_count($str, " Brains ");
```

Output:

```
1
```

I need the expression that should give that result:

```
$str = "Brains Brains.Brains, Brainsasdasdas and another one Brains." // 4 count of word
// echo count of brains of $str with the expression
```

Output should be:

```
4
```

Comment: What regular expressions have you tried then? You only list substr_count

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$str = "Brains Brains.Brains, Brainsasdasdas and another one Brains."; 
$count = 0 ;
$words =  preg_split("/[\s,\.]+/", $str );
foreach ($words as $word) {
    if ($word == "Brains"){
        $count++;
    }
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: ps  please que this as correct answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is to use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to split the string based on using the word you want to count (as a whole word within word boundaries i.e. using `\b` around it in the regex) as a delimiter. `preg_split` will return an array with one more value in it than there were occurrences of the word, so the answer is simply the `count` of that array, minus one. e.g.

```
$str = "Brains Brains.Brains, Brainsasdasdas and another one Brains.";
echo count(preg_split('/\bBrains\b/', $str))-1;
$str = "Brains Brains Brainsasdasdas Brains";
echo count(preg_split('/\bBrains\b/', $str))-1;
$str = "Brains Brainsgdfgdfgdfgfdg";
echo count(preg_split('/\bBrains\b/', $str))-1;
```

Output

```
4
3
1
```